# How do I migrate data from my old schema database to New schema with different database connection

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How do I migrate data inside tables belonging to a Schema A of database A to Tables belonging To schema B of Database B in a mvn project?
Can someone tell me the ways to do it?

I have already written a few SQL scripts and executed them in the SQL editor of Schema A (I just wanted to check if the scripts I have written are correct! So, I created tables belonging to schema B inside schema A) Now how do I actually perform this operation of migrating from tables of schema A to tables of schema B in Java way only?

Note: the design of these tables has been changed hence belong to different schemas across different dbs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use INSERT INTO SELECT statement https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-insert-into-select/